# increase width of span element form left to right on hover in bootstrap 5.2 rtl version

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have an anchor tag with position:relative and a span tag inside it with position:absolute

i want to increase width of span tag on hovering on anchor tag from left to rigth.

i am using bootstrap 5.2 rtl version.this is my code below

html code

```
 <a class="login" href="#" dir="ltr">
                    <i class="fal fa-user"></i>
                    <span  class="my-badge">لطفا وارد شوید!</span>
   </a>
```

css code

```
  .login {
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;

    i {
        color: white;
    }

    .my-badge {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #FF5959;
        height: 12px;
        width: 12px;
        color: transparent;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        top: -2px;
        right: -4px;
        font-size: 8px;
        margin-left: auto;
        transition: width linear .3s;
    }

    &:hover {
        .my-badge {
            height: 20px;
            width: 60px;
            color: white;

        }
    }
}
```

and the result is
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by targeting **.my-badge** in a proper way like **.login:hover > .my-badge {...}** and if you additionally want to change the direction set **right: inherit**. I've updated your code to work in the snippet and include the solution right away. Note: The DIV is just a wrapper for a better experience in the snippet and isn't actually needed to make it work.

```css
.login {
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

i {
    color: white;
 }  

.my-badge {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FF5959;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: -2px;
    right: -4px;
    font-size: 8px;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.login:hover > .my-badge {
    height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    color: white;
    transition: width linear .3s;
}

.login:hover > .my-badge.ltr {
    right: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 50px 0 0 50px">
  <a class="login" href="#" dir="ltr">
    <i class="fal fa-user"></i>
    <span class="my-badge">لطفا وارد شوید!</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="margin: 50px 0 0 50px">
  <a class="login" href="#" dir="ltr">
    <i class="fal fa-user"></i>
    <span class="my-badge ltr">لطفا وارد شوید!</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you it works but i dont know what does this code do exactly? right:inherit @Ferris

Comment: Taken from MDN documentation: The inherit CSS keyword causes the element to take the computed value of the property from its parent element. It can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand property all. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit However, **using auto is also possible** here and might have made more sense for you.